# How to include a Facelets file in a JSP file?

Tags: jsp, jsf-2, include, facelets

I have a JSP page `main.jsp` and in that page I want to include a Facelets page `menu.xhtml`. How can I achieve this? I have searched a lot and there does not seem to be any way.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220275/can-i-import-my-own-jsp-page-into-another-jsp-page/7222401#7222401

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. Facelets (XHTML) is basically the successor of JSP and is supposed to be used as a replacement of JSP. You should migrate all your legacy JSP pages to modern Facelets. Then you can use Facelets' `<ui:include>` to include another Facelets file.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

Answer (score 0):

As a temp hack you may call the JSF page from within an IFrame embedded in the JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

Make main.xhtml. Include jsp with [OmniFaces resourceinclude](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resourceInclude).

So basically you make a dummy xhtml page and include jsp with omnifaces and jsf the normal jsf way.