# <jsp:include or <@include or Tiles

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles, jspinclude

I'm making a Spring MVC web project and I have to have a constant header.

My basic requirement is "We would like to have a header across all screens to show who is logged in to ProjectA."

I've looked at the difference between jsp:include or %@include from here "[What is the difference between <jsp:include page = ... > and <%@ include file = ... >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879906/what-is-the-difference-between-jspinclude-page-and-include-file)" but then I have also come across tiles as per this example "http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse/"

My question is...what is your opinion on which is the better way to implement this.

side note: I am use to master pages in asp.net and cant seem to find something similar in Java / Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `@include` when you need to include static contents in your page i.e., contents that don't change at run-time. When you need dynamic behavior, like the way you've mentioned above, you will probably need `jsp:include`, as your included part will vary based on who is logged in to which project.

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220275/can-i-import-my-own-jsp-page-into-another-jsp-page/7222401#7222401) for more clarification if need be.